# Enlarging target object size by dragging dynamically in fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

I have a canvas application where I can add objects(shapes) by drag and drop.
how can I enlarge size of target object in canvas by fabricjs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scale property of fabricjs object. When you are doing drag & drop you will get an event "object:added", see [this](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html). Within the callback use scale function of fabricjs object, see [this](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#scale).

So basically the code chunk will be like this.

```
canvas.on('object:added', function(options) {
    options.target.scale(2); //where 2 is the scaling factor
});
```